# requireJS fails to load Handsontable

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handsontable

I've been struggling a while to get handsontable to work with requireJS.

On its own, handontable works fantastic.

I get the following error:

```
app.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Handsontable is not a constructor
    at app.js:11
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1693)
    at Module.check (require.js:881)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1136)
    at require.js:134
    at require.js:1186
    at each (require.js:59)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1185)
    at Module.check (require.js:936)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1173)
```

Here is a bare minimum example.
My html code:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
  <script data-main="static/js/app" src="static/js/require.js">
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="static/css/handsontable.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js code (**EDIT: As per Nhor's answer**):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'static',
    waitSeconds: 10,
    paths: {
        // Handsontable full's requirements is in the plugin directory/
        // I shouldn't need them, but incase.
        'pikaday': 'plugins/pikaday/pikaday',
        'zeroclipboard': 'plugins/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard',
        'moment': 'plugins/moment.min',
        // Handsontable is directly in the static folder
        'handsontable': 'handsontable'
    }
});
requirejs([
    'handsontable'
], function(
    Handsontable
) {
    var data = [['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
                ['2008', 10, 11, 12, 13],
                ['2009', 20, 11, 14, 13],
                ['2009', 30, 15, 12, 13]
              ];
    var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example'), {
      data: data,
      colHeaders: true,
      rowHeaders: true,
      minSpareRows: 1,
      minSpareCols: 1,
    });
});
```

According to hansontable's documentation, handsontable has AMD support https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable. It seems to me there is something I do not understand about requireJS. I haven't had this issue with other modules I imported.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you using? Having had exactly the same problem today, reverting to version 0.31.2 fixed it. Using anything below 0.32.0 works fine. I know this might not the a perfect SO solution/response, but it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! "upgrading" to version 0.31.2 fixed it for me. (had 0.32 beta).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `handsontable` library path. `RequireJS` needs to know the path of all the files that you want to use, which means you have to specify paths within the `requirejs.config` function. The paths can either point to your local filesystem or to a remote resource throught HTTP. You can read more about it here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

---

@edit

Actually I made a little mistake saying that path can point to the filesystem. That's because I'm used to reflecting my filesystem directory structure in HTTP routing, but in fact the path should point to a place in which the file resides on your HTTP server, so for example if the address is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/handsontable.js`, the `baseUrl` should be `./static/js`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Nhor. I still get the same error however. (I tried before as well. I updated my question with the new app.js)

Comment: Actually I made a little mistake saying that path can point to the filesystem. That's because I'm used to reflecting my filesystem directory structure in HTTP routing, but in fact the path should point to a place in which the file resides on your HTTP server, so for example if the address is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/handsontable`, the `baseUrl` should be `./static/js`.